# Simplifying $\cosh \mathrm{arcsinh} \ x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

How can I simplify the following:
$$\cosh \mathrm{arcsinh} \ x$$
I know that an expression of the form $f(g^{-1}(x))$ where $f$ and $g$ are trigonometric functions can be simplified by constructing a right triangle. Is there an analgous construction for the hyperbolic functions?

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is the result. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recall that $\cosh^{2}(x)-\sinh^{2}(x)=1$ and take $x=\mathrm{arcsinh(y)}$.

On the hyperbola $x^{2}-y^{2}=1$ you can interpret the $x$ and $y$ components as $\cosh(A)$ and $\sinh(A)$ respectively (where $A$ is the area described in the diagram). Putting $A=\mathrm{arcsinh(t)}$ and recalling that the $x$ and $y$ components satisfy $x^{2}-y^{2}=1$ gives you the formula. This is analogous to drawing triangles to solve for an identity.

[image: picture]

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that. This solves it nicely, but relies on the identity relating $\sinh$ and $\cosh$; is there a more general method that would work for, say, $\mathrm{csch}\ \mathrm{arctanh}\ x$?

Comment: I don't know of a more general method but I usually try to reduce the expression so that it is in terms of $\sinh(x)$, $\cosh(x)$, $\tanh(x)$, $\mathrm{arcsinh(x)}$, $\mathrm{arccosh(x)}$, and $\mathrm{arctanh(x)}$. Then I would apply identities to solve. So for your example I would first note that $csch(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})=\frac{1}{\sinh(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})}$. Then I would note that $x=\tanh(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})=\frac{\sinh(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})}{\cosh(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})}=\frac{\sinh(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^{2}(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})}}$. Solve for $\sinh(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})$.

Comment: It occurred to me that to solve your example I could have just noted that $csch^{2}(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})=\cot^{2}(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})-1=\frac{1}{\tanh^{2}(\mathrm{arctanh(x)})}-1=\frac{1}{x^{2}}-1$. You will have to specify cases for the formula since you need to take a square root and $csch(x)$ changes sign.